# comparing 2 string array in java and print the same element from the both arrays

Tags: java, arrays, csv

below is my work so far i have used 2 csv files and made 2 different arrays which represents 2 csv file data now what i am want to do that is i want to compare that 2 arrays and print the same vlaues or elements which are same in both arrays this is where i am having difficulty

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CSVReaderw {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String csvFile1 = "/Users/Documents/AD.csv";
    String csvFile2 = "/Users/Desktop/database.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    String[] ad = null;
    String[] database = null;

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile1));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
             ad = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            //System.out.println("AD [id= " + ad[2] +"]");

        }
        System.out.println("second file result starts here");
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile2));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

           database = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
           //System.out.println("ID =" + database[0]);
        }

        List<String> commonListLambda = Arrays.stream(database)
        .filter(x -> Arrays.asList(ad).contains(x))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(commonListLambda);
            // List<String> commonList = new ArrayList<>();
// 
//             for(int i = 0; i < ad.length; i++){
//                 if(Arrays.asList(databse).contains(ad[i]))
//                     commonList.add(ad[i]);
//                  }
//             
//             System.out.println(commonList);



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

Edit:
see the updated code as we dicuessed here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: in that questions they are only showing how to compare strings i want to comapre the values which is on the arrays and print the same values from arrays

Comment: `if(ad[i] == database[j])` You are comparing string that you get from the files. It is exactly the same solution.

Comment: so instead of using  ==  i should .equals let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are rewriting again your array, instead of adding data to it.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           database = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
```

General logic is wrong, you need to compare cell in one file to the cell in other file.

Please see suggested solution, I tried to make code self-explanatory.

```
public class CSVReaderw {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String adDotCsv = "/Users/Documents/AD.csv";
        String databaseDotCsv = "/Users/Desktop/database.csv";
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        List<String> databaseList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String[]> adList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(databaseDotCsv));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                databaseList.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(cvsSplitBy)));
            }

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(adDotCsv));

            line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                adList.add(line.split(cvsSplitBy));
            }

            List<String[]> commonList = new ArrayList<>();

            String cellCInAdFile = null;

            for (String[] rowInAdList : adList) {
                cellCInAdFile = Arrays.toString(rowInAdList).split(",")[2].trim();

                for (String cellAinDatabaseFile : databaseList) {
                    if (cellCInAdFile.equals(cellAinDatabaseFile.trim())) {
                        commonList.add(rowInAdList);
                    }
                }
            }

            for (String[] rowInCommonList : commonList) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.asList(rowInCommonList));
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so i have to replace my inner for loop  right?? @fg78nc

Comment: I did not study attention to your code. This is complete solution which will compare two arrays and return List of common elements. Let me know if you need additional help

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < ad.length; i++)
            {
               for(int j = 0; j < database.length; ++j)
                  {
                     if(!Arrays.asList(ad).contains(database[i]))
                        commonList.add(database[i]);
                        System.out.println(commonList);   //value is in both arrays
                        
                   }
            }
this what i did but it's not working gives me cannot find symbol on commonList

Comment: You don't need outer loop, only one loop is enough.

Comment: i took out the other for loop and declare the commonlist like this String[] commonList = null; now it gives me this error error: cannot find symbol
                        commonList.add(database[i]);
                                           ^
  symbol:   method add(String)
  location: variable commonList of type String[]

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                         ^
  symbol:   variable Collectors
this the error

Comment: `import java.util.stream.Collectors;`

Comment: error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final
.filter(x -> Arrays.asList(ad).contains(x))
                                       ^
1 error

Comment: i did try your first version in that i got empty list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150490/discussion-between-fg78nc-and-newlearner).